# Create a static class per thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I know this technically isn't possible to my knowledge but I would like to mimic the behaviour.  Any ideas welcome.

Consider the following:

Base class `Vehicle` with associated property `NumberOfWheels`

Derived class `Car` which inherits from `Vehicle`.  Therefore all properties of
`Vehicle` are available in `Car`.  I can create a static version of `Car` in my Program.cs and in my library of generic utility code, I can reference `Vehicle.NumberOfWheels` and assuming I've created a static Car class, it will return the Car's wheels count.

I now want to run this code in two threads, Thread 1 dealing with Car stuff and Thread 2 dealing with Bicycle stuff, however I would like each thread to have its own **instance** of the static class.

Therefore when I call `Vehicle.NumberOfWheels` from Thread 1 I get 4 and then I call it from Thread 2 I get 2.

Complicated I know as static classes are per AppDomain rather than Thread. Anyone have any good ideas without having to pass the an instance of the class in the constructor of each of my utility classes?

Edit - adding sample classes for clarity

Assuming I want to start two servers each with their own settings and I want to load the config for each server from a settings file into the following structure. (This code is still abstract as I cannot share the exact code, but hopefully helps for clarity

```
public class Options : AbsOptions, IOptions
{
    public int Port { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int IdleConnectionTimeout { get; set; }
}

public class Server1Options : Options
{
}

public class Server2Options : Options
{
}
```

The initialisation code in Programe.cs can then be created like this...

```
var server1Options.init() //code in here to set the properties for server1;
var server2Options.init() //code in here to set the properties for server2;

Thread server1 = new Thread(AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening);
        server1.Start();
Thread server1 = new Thread(AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening);
        server2.Start();
```

I want Thread 1 to be able to make a generic call to `Options`
something like:

```
    public void StartListening() 
    {
        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Any;
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Options.Port);

        Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        try
        {
            listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
            listener.Listen();
            Console.Writeline($"Waiting for client connection on port {Options.Port}...");
        }
}
```

and this will get the options from server1 options - specifically in the start up method, I call options.port without the method knowing anything about Server1 or Server2, it just knows to ask for the Option value in order to operate.

Comment: Are you looking for `ThreadStaticAttribute`? `[ThreadStatic] private static Vehicle MyVehicle = new Vehicle()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?view=net-7.0

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Perhaps.. I presume I could load the static properties at the beginning of each thread and then access them uniquely on the thread?

Comment: Why do you need it static at all?  In the real work there is no one and only instance of "Car".

Comment: I'd go with Erik: static is for behavior that exists across all instances. Your `NumberOfWheels` certainly belongs to a specific `Vehicle`-instance.

Comment: A car can have more or less than 4 wheels and bikes can have more or less than 2

Comment: "and assuming I've created a static Car class" Eeeehm, why do you assume that? Seems your thread-based problem is just based on that whrong assumption. Can you share the code for your `Vehicle`- and `Car`-classes, please?

Comment: I assume your actual problem isn't about threads nor static at all, but instead a bad class-design. Having said this it would really help if we saw your code for these classes.

Comment: ` [...] its own instance of the static class.` Remove the word "static" from this sentence, and you got your answer. With what limited information you've given us, there's absolutely no reason to have a static class representing a Vehicule. Each thread should just create its own object instance.

Comment: @Spanners: Yes, you can mark such properties with `[ThreadStatic]`

Comment: your update doesn't help. You should provide the design for your `Vehicle`- and `Car`-class, not the server-setup.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain I used Vehicle and Car as an example, the updated code is the actual thing I am trying to do. Eg: start a server using the start method which is a generic method which only has the Option.Port value that is different.  Rather than write two Start methods, I have one which I need to be able to reference a thread specific value for the Port.

Comment: than please don't write two completely different things into your question. First you mention cars, just to mention servers afterwards. Anyway thjere's nothing *static*  in your class, so I still don't get your point. The only thing that *looks* like if it were (but certainly it is *not), is this `Options.Port`-thing. However `Port` is just a (non-static) member of the base-class, so you can easily access it via your current (derived) class instance without the `Options`-name. Just do `new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's unclear for me what do you mean by

> Create a static *class* per thread (*italic* is mine, D.B.)

> each thread to have its own **instance** of the static class

You can't *create* a static class, they *don't have instances*. However, you can make `static` *field* (or property) be different for different threads. If it's your problem, then you can try either [ThreadStaticAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?view=net-7.0) or more general [ThreadLocal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?view=net-7.0) class, e.g.

```
public class Vehicle {
  public int NumberOfWheels { get; set; }
}

public class Car : Vehicle {
  public Car(int wheels) {
    NumberOfWheels = wheels;
  }

  public override string ToString() =>
    $"Car with {NumberOfWheels} wheels";

  // static field which is different for different threads 
  [ThreadStatic] public static Car Shared;
}
```

And then

```
// Truck in UI thread
Car.Shared = new Car(6);

// 4 Wheels in car task 
var car = Task.Run(() => {
  // Note, that UI thread still work with 6 wheel truck
  Car.Shared = new Car(4);

  return Car.Shared;
});

// 2 Wheels in bike task 
var bike = Task.Run(() => {
  // It doesn't spoil either ui thread (6 wheel truck) or car (4 wheel) 
  Car.Shared = new Car(2);

  return Car.Shared;
});

await Task.WhenAll(car, bike);

// Note that car, bike and ui have their own Car.Shared
string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
  $"Truck: {Car.Shared}",
  $"Car:   {car.Result}",
  $"Bike:  {bike.Result}");
```

Output:

```
Truck: Car with 6 wheels
Car:   Car with 4 wheels
Bike:  Car with 2 wheels
```

**Edit:**

Technically, you can have `NumberOfWheels` be thread `static`:

```
public class Vehicle {
  [ThreadStatic]
  private static int s_NumberOfWheels;

  public static int NumberOfWheels {
    get => s_NumberOfWheels
    set => s_NumberOfWheels = value;
  }
}

public class Car : Vehicle {
  public override string ToString() => $"{NumberOfWheels} wheels";
}
```

But the design looks quite strange

- Why some `static` properties are dependent on threads and some are not?
- Today we usually work with `Task`, not `Thread` and different unconnected tasks can well use the same thread from the pool.

Comment: Accepting this answer as it solves my problem but credit to @MakePeaceGreatAgain. My class design was wrong and so I have now refactored the code

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone have any good ideas without having to pass the instance of
> the class in the constructor of each of my utility classes?

Not really, only by using a ParameterizedThreadStart, which admittedly is similar to passing it to the utility class constructor, except here you can use the same instance of your utility class.

```
var server1Options.init();
var server2Options.init();

Thread server1 = new Thread(AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening);
server1.Start(server1Options);

Thread server1 = new Thread(AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening);
server2.Start(server2Options);

public void StartListening(object parameter) 
{
     var options = parameter as Options;
     ....
}
```

From an OOP point of view, it may not be necessary to inherit from Options just because you have a different set of options, nonetheless this works.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem has nothing to do with threads nor `static` - in fact your code does not contain *any* static member. All the members of the `Options`-class are directly available in your server-instances, e.g. you can just do `myServer1Options.Port`. So every `ServerOption` *has* its own `Port`, no need for any `ThreadStatic` or similar things.

When you want to provide the `ServerOptions` to some thread, do so by using the [overload of `Start` that expects an `object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?view=net-7.0#system-threading-thread-start(system-object)):

```
Thread server1 = new Thread(AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening);
server1.Start(server1Options);
```